# Spring Integration - JMS to Kafka message transfer - End to End Transaction

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-integration, activemq-classic

I am consuming messages from JMS ActiveMQ using the following code:

```
<jms:message-driven-channel-adapter
        id="helloJMSAdapater" destination="helloJMSQueue" connection-factory="jmsConnectionfactory"
        channel="helloChannel" extract-payload="true" />
<integration:channel id="helloChannel" />
```

My requirement is to consume from here and post it to Kafka outbound adapter. Using the below config:

```
<int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter
            id="kafkaOutboundChannelAdapter"
            kafka-producer-context-ref="kafkaProducerContext"
            channel="inputToKafka">
</int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter>
```

Here are what i want to achieve:

1. My queue is a durable topic and dont want to acknowledge the records unless it is successfully published to Kafka. In short, i want to have a transaction behaviour from consuming message from jms to publishing it to Kafka.
2. I noticed that my messages are immediately dequeued and if processing encounters some exception, i am unable to reprocess it. I dont want that to happen.
3. Also, when kafka encounters some issue, i want it to be returned to some method so that i can persist the failure message and as said before does not want to acknowledge it.

I am really struggling to get it to work. Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really can have `transaction-manager` on the `<jms:message-driven-channel-adapter>` to start TX.

When `<int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter>` throws an exception it causes the TX to be ralled back and therefore the message will be requeued.

If you are interested in the persisting errors, there is an `error-channel` option on the `<jms:message-driven-channel-adapter>`, but you still have to re-throw exception to let TX to rallback.

To make all that to work you should be sure that there is only single thread from the begging to the end. No `<queue>` or `executor` channel in the flow.

Also it isn't clear why do you use so old Apache Kafka still...

Comment: Thanks Artem. I will give it a try and revert. About Apache Kafka , i have taken the reference from Spring resources.  Is there a way to trap the exception from Kafka and persist the erroneous message to some store. Does kafka adapter provide something like error channel.

Comment: You also need `sync=true` on the (new 2.0) kafka adapter; you can add an error channel to the JMS inbound adapter; the message payload is a `MessagingException` with `cause` and `failedMessage` properties.

Comment: No, but that can be done via `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice`: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#expression-advice